# C: Trouble understanding pointers in this program

Tags: c, variables, pointers

I need to find the values of i and j after the following code is executed:

```
int i = 2;
int j = 2;
int *p = &i;
int *q = &j;
i++;
j--;
*p = *q + 2;
*q = *p + 3;
p=q;
*p = *q + 1;
```

Let me describe what I think is happening in this code. 
In the third and fourth line:

```
int *p = &i;
int *q = &j;
```

pointers p and q are initialized to the addresses of i and j, respectively. 
In the 5th and 6th lines:

```
i++;
j--;
```

i becomes 3 and j becomes 1. This causes *p to be 3 and *q to be 1.

In the 7th line,

```
*p = *q + 2
```

means the value that p points to is equal to the value that q points to plus` 2, so i becomes 3.

In the next line:

```
*q = *p + 3;
```

j becomes 6.

I'm not sure what happens in this next line:

```
p = q;
```

I think it means: "the address of i is equal to address of j". I do not know what the final values of i and j would be in this situation. Can you help me understand what is happening?

Comment: `p = q;` means that `p` now points to where `q` points, which is at `j`.  The line after that means that `j` ends up with the value `7`, and both `*p` and `*q` also evaluate to 7.  You got the rest right, though.

Comment: one way to make this easier is to run it in a debugger (an IDE based one does it best because you can see each variable change after each step).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Imagine your memory looks like this after the initial initialization of `p` and `q`:

```
+---+     +---+
| p | --> | i |
+---+     +---+

+---+     +---+
| q | --> | j |
+---+     +---+
```

After you do

```
p = q;
```

it looks like this instead:

```
+---+
| p | --\
+---+    \     +---+
          >--> | j |
+---+    /     +---+
| q | --/
+---+
```

Comment: how do you do this so fast?? :D

Answer (score 3):

```
p = q;
```

This simply means that now `p` is pointing to the same thing that `q` was pointing to, i.e. `j`.